# Customize Material UI Slider Label - last-child

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

In Material-ui, by default Slider's labels look like position centered:

[image: Slider's labels text centered]

But I need space-between position of both labels. Like this:

[image: Slider's labels text space-between]

I use '&:last-child' property for class markLabel. According to documentation https://material-ui.com/ru/api/slider/

This code will apply styles only for markLabel. But doesn't work for '&:last-child':

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSlider: {
      markLabel: {
        color: "red",
        transform: "none",
        "&:last-child": {
          color: "green",
          transform: "translateX(-100%)"
        }
      },
    }
  }
});
```

Here is SandBox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-override-table-padding-on-last-child-forked-bt2lr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Trying to select it using `:last-child` does not work, because that element _is not_ the last child.

Answer (score 3):

I have an exactly same issue,
but couldn't find out any good solution.
so i used like this because I have only two label - start and end.....

```
  markLabel:{
    color:'#b3b3b3',
    fontFamily: "'Montserrat', sans-serif",
    fontWeight:700,
    marginTop:6,
    transform:'translateX(-100%)',
    '&[data-index="0"]' : {
      transform:'none'
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but i solved this issue in a sort of hacky way, using styled components. Perhaps of use to someone at some point. My component has a dynamic number of marks, so i use the "max" parameter passed to the slider to find the last index.

```
const StyledSlider = styled(Slider)`
  *[class*='MuiSlider-markLabel-'][data-index='0'] {
    transform: none;
  }

  *[class*='MuiSlider-markLabel-'][data-index='${({ max }) => max}'] {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
`;
```